# Counts based on hour SQL

Tags: sql, hiveql

How can I get the count per hour?

```
select count_hr_1, count_hr_2, count_hr_3 from db.table where year=2018 and month=01 and day=02 and hour=01 OR hour=02 OR hour=03;
```

This SQL/Query is probably invalid but I want to get the counts of hour 1,2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to process the resultset as multiple rows instead of one, you could use [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp):

```
select hour, count(*)
  from db.table
  where
    year = 2018
    and month = 1
    and day = 2
    and hour in (1, 2, 3)
  group by hour
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(case when hour = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as count_hr_1, 
       sum(case when hour = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as count_hr_2, 
       sum(case when hour = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as count_hr_3
from db.table 
where year = 2018 
and month = 1 
and day = 2 
and hour in (1,2,3)
```